# Offline installation of android sdk platform

Tags: android

I recently imported an Android project into Android studio but it required android 22 platform to run(I have android platform 25 installed). I tried installing it via the Android SDK Manager but installation keeps failing (probably due to Internet connectivity issues). I decided to copy the platform's download url and successfully downloaded it. How do I install the platform offline? I am using android studio 2.3.3

Comment: Find your sdk path in android studio and add your sdk package in required folder.Note:Android studio updated it version and unlock it new features.

Comment: My sdk path is ~/Android/Sdk and the the package is a zipped file (android-22_r02.zip). Do you mean that I should copy it in there?